# How get distance driving between 2 point by google api

Tags: android

When i have Lat,Longi of 2 Point.
The people can to help me , How get distance (mode: driving of google map) between 2 point in code android?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

You can get distance from address of location `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins="+a+"&destinations="+b+"&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false`
with a=addressFrom, b=addressTo

If you have lat,long of location, you can get address of that location as:

```
 double latiTude = 10.3929393;
 double longiTude = 150.93984884;

 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
  GeoPoint p= new GeoPoint((int) (latiTude * 1E6), (int) (longiTude * 1E6));
  List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                                                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                                                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
    if (address.size() > 0) 
    {
    String addressFroLatLong= "";
    for (int i = 0; i < address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) 
    {   addressFroLatLong+= address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
    }   
   }
```